# Upgrading Elastic Beanstalk worker tier to 1.1 with .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the **eb** CLI tool to create my application and environments on Elastic Beanstalk, but finding that it's creating a Worker 1.0 tier.

Is there a way I can use .ebextensions or a script that runs on "eb start" that can upgrade the tier to v1.1?

Comment: Just curious to know if my answer below solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `eb init`, eb generates a file with name `.elasticbeanstalk/config` in your app source directory.

You can modify the tier version in this file.
You can change from `EnvironmentTier=Worker::SQS/HTTP::1.0` to `EnvironmentTier=Worker::SQS/HTTP::1.1` and when you launch an environment it will launch with worker tier 1.1.

Tier version cannot be modified via ebextensions.